# Uniqueness of smooth manifold obtained from glueing two manifolds along their boundary

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have a question about a result in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifold(2nd Edition).

Theorem 9.29 (Attaching Smooth Manifolds Along Their Boundaries). Let $M$
and $N$ be smooth $n$-manifolds with nonempty boundaries, and suppose $h:\partial M \rightarrow \partial N$ is a diffeomorphism. Let$M \cup_h N $ be the adjunction space formed by
identifying each $x \in \partial N$ with $h(x)\in \partial M$. Then $M \cup_h N $ is a topological manifold
(without boundary), and has a smooth structure such that there are regular domains
$M', N' $ diffeomorphic to $M ,N$, respectively, and satisfying $M'\cup N'=M \cup_h N $, $M'\cap N'=\partial N'=\partial M'$

In the proof of Theorem 9.29 we construct a smooth structure on the glued quotient space $M \cup_h N $. In such construction we take a collar neighborhood of $\partial M$ and $\partial N$ respectively, identify the union of them in the quotient space with $\partial M \times (-1,1)$. And the atlas on $M \cup_h N $ is the union of the atlas on $IntM, IntN$ respectively, and the atlas on $\partial M \times (-1,1)$.

Theorem 9.29 only claim the existence of such smooth structure. However from a following example (the double of a smooth manifold with boundary) it seems that the author assumes that we can get a canonical smooth structure on $M \cup_h N $ once $M,N$ and $h$ are given, independent of the choice of the collar neighborhoods. I'm thus wondering whether we have uniqueness from the setting of Theorem 9.29 (only $M,N$ and $h$ are fixed), and how to prove such uniqueness(if there exist).

Comment: Given two objects satisfying the "Then..." sentence, have you tried showing the map sending $M'$ to $M''$, $N'$ to $N''$ (' indicating the first object, '' the second) is a diffeomorphism? Seems like it should be, and that should be unique enough.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how to show that it is a (local) diffeomorphism near the glued boundaries. If this uniqueness holds, that will be the best we could expect, of course.

Comment: On second thought, the "Then..." sentence makes no reference to $h$, so it seems Jack may have left out a compatibility condition. Really $\partial N' = \partial M'$ should correspond to the original diffeomorphism $h$ under the diffeomorphisms $\phi \colon N \to N'$, $\psi \colon M \colon \to M'$. That is, we should also have $phi(n) = \psi(h(n))$ for all $n \in \partial N$. This holds for Jack's $\pi$ function. Otherwise my proposed diffeomorphism isn't even well-defined; just replace $\phi$ by some other diffeomorphism, say. I agree his example tacitly assumes uniqueness, so is incomplete.